# Get unavailable date in a datepicker (Swift)

Tags: swift, uidatepicker

I have a UIDatePicker which is available for days from today to the next week ( from Date() to Date().day + 7 ).

Suppose that today is 30th day of the month, so the available days to choose are 30th day of this month and first to 6th day of next month.

In this case, I need to change the datePicker month to next month as the user change day from 30 to 1.

But the problem is: 
"When I change the day to an invalid one, the .change method give me the least valid day."

**Example:**

---

**Assumptions:**

1. Today = 28 July.
2. Choosable dates = 28 July to 3 August.

---

**What I need:**

1. User can not choose the days before 28 July and not after 3 August.
2. When user wants to change day to 1, 2 or 3 August, the datePicker itself change the month to August and make 1, 2 and 3 available to
   be chosen by user.

---

**Main Problem**

1. When user change the day to 1, 2 or 3, I can not get the 1, 2 or 3! and it returns me "28"!

Comment: have you set minimum and maximum dates for the date picker ? Plz set minimum date as current date and maximum as per your logic .

Comment: @ManuRaphy Yes I did, but I want to make the month change Automatic!
Would you please take a deeper look in my example?

Comment: you main problem is that your user cannot change the month _and_ day at the same time in `UIDatePicker`, you need to implement your own `UIPickerView` what contains those 7 days only so your user can scroll though smoothly; not too complex job but you need to extract/create/convert a `Date()` object from the current row after the selection is done.

Comment: @holex Yes, Finally I did that yesterday. In fact, it is impossible to get date before they chose. And according to unavailability of days in next month before changing the month, I can not use UIDatePicker to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Just set **maximumDate** property of your `UIDatePicker` to desired date.

```
func setupDatePicker(){

   var currDateComponents = getDateComponents(fromDate: Date())
   var maxDateComponents = currDateComponents

   if let date = currDateComponents?.day{
        maxDateComponents?.day = date + 7
   }

   self.datePicker?.maximumDate = getDate(fromDateComponents: maxDateComponents)

}

func getDateComponents(fromDate date: Date?)-> DateComponents?{
    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    var dateComponents: DateComponents? = nil
    if(date != nil){
        dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year], from: date!)
    }

    return dateComponents
 }

 func getDate(fromDateComponents dateComponents:DateComponents?)-> Date?{
    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)

    if let componentsBasedDate = calendar.date(from: dateComponents!) {
        return componentsBasedDate
    }

    return nil
 }
```

Comment: I have set Maximum and minimum date. The problem is something else, Would you please take a deeper look in my example?

Answer (score 0):

Call this function in viewDidLoad to setup calendar for setting maximum and minimum date:

```
fileprivate func setupCalendar() {
    datePicker.minimumDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 0, to: ServerTime.sharedInstance.nowTime)
    datePicker.maximumDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: +7, to: ServerTime.sharedInstance.nowTime)
}
```

for calculate days between shown date and current date I've used this method:

```
extension Date {
 //Calculate days between two day objects
func daysBetween(_ date: Date) -> Int {
    let calendar = NSCalendar.current

    // Replace the hour (time) of both dates with 00:00
    let date1 = calendar.startOfDay(for: date)
    let date2 = calendar.startOfDay(for: self)

    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: date1, to: date2)

    return components.day ?? 0  // This will return the number of day(s) between dates
  }
}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering, but I think no one have got the main problem, except @holex of course.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it is impossible to get date before they chose. And according to unavailability of days in next month before changing the month, I can not use UIDatePicker to handle it.

So Finally I implemented my custom UIPickerView.

as @holex said.

Thank you all for answering.